# Anyone mangaged to use google cloud loadbalancing from https to http?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have set up an instance reachable on http.

I have set up an instance group containing that instance.

I have set up Loadbalancing using an self signed ssl cert.

The external IP of the LB and the instance can be reached.

The forwarding of the request from the LB runs into an time out.

The config for Loadbalancing says "you have 0 instances without errors, you have 1 instance with errors."

I don't see any log entries in the apache logs coming from the lb frontend.

There is no http connection from Google addresses showing up.

Any ideas where to look for or hints to a good guide (not the rather good google docu)?

Comment: I don't see how this issue is programming related. It's more suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I checked Serverfault before but found no relevant questions over there but here. As crossposting is a bad manner I decided to put it here. As it is a rather common thing in enterprise web-app development there might be at least some programmers like me that have been running in this issue.

Comment: You being a programmer or you wanting to address programmers doesn't make this a programming related question. The solution will not include programming and since we're all smart coders we will check serverfault.com if we run into this or similar issues. I flagged the question as off-topic, let's see if anyone thinks the same way.

Comment: Have you checked whether the URL where you redirect to is externally available / available from the load balancer? This does sound like a firewall / routing issue.

Comment: guess there is some sort of bug cause the healtcheck is working

130.211.1.162 - - [09/Oct/2015:17:17:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 310 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Compute Engine HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) with HTTP backend services. Select HTTP as Backend services protocol. For health check, use HTTP health check. Add GCE firewall rules to open tcp:80 for 130.211.0.0/22 and tcp:443 for 0.0.0.0/0 source IP ranges.

Comment: Thats exactly what I have done, but it says the backend has a failure and times out after 30 sec. FW Rules are open as well. The backend called solo is working to. Even tried it with a simple index.html and restarting the Backend - no go :-( seems to be broken.

Comment: What's the status of the healthcheck? If healthcheck fails, follow this post to debug it: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2015/07/Debugging-Health-Checks-in-Load-Balancing-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html